# Mule FailedToQueueEventException Quartz connection

Tags: mule, mule-component, mule-esb

I have below quartz inbound component to trigger an kafka event. But it seems to be throwing SEDA queue Exception.

```
<quartz:connector name="myQuartzConnector" validateConnections="true">
    <receiver-threading-profile maxThreadsActive="1"/>
</quartz:connector>

<flow name="quartz-scheduler-kafka-consumer-trigger-flow">
    <quartz:inbound-endpoint jobName="Trigger-Kafka-Consumer-Quartz-Job" repeatInterval="1" responseTimeout="10000" connector-ref="myQuartzConnector" doc:name="Quartz">
        <quartz:event-generator-job/>
    </quartz:inbound-endpoint>
    <component class="org.my.myKafkaCOnsumer" doc:name="Java KafkaConsumer"/>
</flow>
```

Quartz is used to trigger the Kafka consumer flow. The control does not return back to the scheduler till the Kafka consumer connection ends in the java component. Kafka consumer connection will  never end as it is is in recursive while(true) loop. By chance if Kafka connections ends, the quartz scheduler should retrigger the java component which reopens the kafka connection.

```
Message               : The queue for 'SEDA Stage quartz-scheduler-kafka-consumer-trigger-flow.stage1' did not accept new event within 30000 MILLISECONDS.
Payload               : {NullPayload}
Payload Type          : org.mule.transport.NullPayload
Element               : null @ message-gateway-profile-update-api:null:null
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Root Exception stack trace:
org.mule.api.service.FailedToQueueEventException: The queue for 'SEDA Stage quartz-scheduler-kafka-consumer-trigger-flow.stage1' did not accept new event within 30000 MILLISECONDS.
    at org.mule.processor.SedaStageInterceptingMessageProcessor.enqueue(SedaStageInterceptingMessageProcessor.java:139)
    at org.mule.processor.SedaStageInterceptingMessageProcessor.processNextAsync(SedaStageInterceptingMessageProcessor.java:102)
    at org.mule.processor.AsyncInterceptingMessageProcessor.process(AsyncInterceptingMessageProcessor.java:103)
    at org.mule.execution.ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.execute(ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.java:27)
```

[Flow snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/odj9P.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is caused because the Quartz endpoint is set to trigger faster than the flow can process the messages. This flow has a default processing strategy [queued-asynchronous, which means that the events triggered by the Quartz endpoint are sent to a SEDA queue](https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-runtime/3.9/flow-processing-strategies#queued-asynchronous-flow-processing-strategy), then processed by flow threads as available. The Quartz endpoint is set to repeat every 1 ms, which is very low. There is very little chance of the component to process in that time. When the thread pool used by the flow is exhausted, then the SEDA queue starts to get filled. When the elements in the queue exceed the default timeout to get a thread to get execute, you receive the error. This issue is described in the KB https://help.mulesoft.com/s/article/Error-The-queue-for-SEDA-queue-name-did-not-accept-new-event-within-30000-MILLISECONDS

You could change the flow processing strategy to synchronous to reuse the queue from the connector to execute and avoid the queueing, but the repeatInterval seems to be unrealistically small.

On a side note, the [Quartz connector](https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-runtime/3.9/quartz-connector) has been deprecated since a long time ago. It has been replaced by the [Poll scope](https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-runtime/3.9/poll-reference).

Answer (score 0):

> The control does not return back to the schedule

This is incorrect statement. Scheduler has no idea how previous flow ends. In fact old flow continues to execute and event to new process starts.
You can see it if you put logger in the begiinig of the flow as first component after scheduler.

Actually, since you are listening for messages it shpuld be no scheduler. Listener should be the source of the flow. It should look like this:

```
<flow name="quartz-scheduler-kafka-consumer-trigger-flow">
    <component class="org.my.myKafkaCOnsumer" doc:name="Java KafkaConsumer"/>
</flow>
```

[image]

Here is a little more about multiple schedules https://simpleflatservice.com/mule4/Multipleschedules.html

Comment: Yes you are correct. I take back that particular statement. But I dont want to see this timeout exception. Any help in this case will be useful. I am not able to open the link you gave due to firewall issues right now.

Comment: What timeout exception? I do not see any. If you are talking about listening for message and having timeout... It shuld not be this way. Listener should be the source of flow not the scheduler. I had updated my answer.

Comment: My project uses Mule 3+ & there is no possibilities of upgrading to Mule 4. The Kafka listener supported in Mule 3 does not provide ways to manual offset commit. I want to have full control over commit and hence used java component to poll kafka. After the java layer opens Kafka connection, it will go into recursive while(true) loop, poll kafka & pass records to subflow for processing. Quartz is used to start the flow on api deployment. If connection ends in java component, java should be re-triggered. This re-trigger will not be time based. Is there any other component to achieve this please?

Comment: Sounds like good design. I would do exactly the same. But since you have this issue in the quartz scheduler (and you don't use it actually) then you should double check its settings. May I recommend start delay=0 and interval 1,000,000 months? In this case scheduler will run only once and you will have full control inside Java component. BTW - separate scheduler flow and exceution flow. In this case issue will be clear where it belongs. I would also double check how re-trigger done in your case. Afetr all issue is too much connections - find where they are.